# Cron job doesnt run

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

Im running ubuntu server, and im trying to run a script every hour.
What I tried is:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and then I add this to the end of the file:

```
MAILTO="info@email.com"
30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/scripts/cronscript.php
```

The script doesnt seem to be running, and im not getting the email.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to use phpcli

Comment: I didn't see any problem in your crontabl content. Will you do a `/etc/init.d/cron restart` as root to make sure that cron service is actually running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using:

```
30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget "http://example.com/scripts/cronscript.php"
```

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-f` flag of php to tell it to take that file as input:

```
MAILTO="info@email.com"
30 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/scripts/cronscript.php
```

That is, of course, if your php *is actually located* at `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cURL, like this:

```
curl http://foobar.com/scripts/cronscript.php
```

If you need it to run silently:

```
curl --silent http://foobar.com/scripts/cronscript.php
```

To add Gzip handling:

```
curl --compressed http://foobar.com/scripts/cronscript.php
```

I usually use both, like:
curl --silent --compressed http://foobar.com/scripts/cronscript.php